# How to iterate over a grails list in javascript

Tags: javascript, grails

I have this grails controller which returns me a list of Strings:

```
class UserController {
  def getUsers = {
    def users = Lists.asList("user1", "user2", "user3")
    render users : users;
  }
}
```

And a javascript which calls the above controller:

```
    var displayUsers = function(users) {
       for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          console.log(users[i];
// this iterates over each character in the users object and not over                 
// it's elements
// users objects is interpreted as a string object and not as a list
       }
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.expand-group').on('click', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getUsers',
            type: "GET",
            data: {}
        }).done(function(data, textStatus) {
               displayUsers(data);
        });
    });
});
```

My output is the following:

```
[
'
u
s
e
r
s
'
:
[
'
u
...
```

So how can I tell javascript to see my users object as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should send the response as a JSON object (from grails.converters package)

```
def getUsers = {
    def users = Lists.asList("user1", "user2", "user3")
    render users as JSON;
}
```

Comment: glad to hear that (nod)